# undefined property error when using muodules::run in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I try use modules::run in my custom library to get all new messages received from contact us form and display it in the header ..

modules run is called fine as i tested it by echo something but when i call some method from the model of the module i get this error

[image]

This is the code of my library

```
 <?php

if (!defined("BASEPATH"))
    exit("No direct script access allowed");

class back extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->helper("form");
        $this->load->library("form_validation");
        $this->lang->load("back", "arabic");
    }


    public function view($page_name, $data = NULL) {
        $h_data["username"] = $this->get_username();
        $h_data["new_cases_reports_count"] = Modules::run('cases/admin_cases/count_new_cases_reports');

        $this->load->view("back/header", $h_data);
        $this->load->view($page_name, $data);
        $this->load->view("back/footer");
    }


}
```

The code of controller

```
    <?php

if (!defined("BASEPATH"))
    exit("No direct script access allowed");

class Admin_cases extends back {

    private $c_name = "admin_cases_";

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->lang->load("cases_back", "arabic");
        $this->load->model("cases_back_model", "cases");
        $this->load->library("form_validation");
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters("<label class='control-label error'><i class='fa fa-times-circle-o'></i>", "</label>");


        $this->_is_logged_in();
    }


    public function count_new_cases_reports() {
        echo 1;
        echo $this->cases->count_new_cases_reports();


    }


}
```

The code of the model

```
    <?php

if (!defined("BASEPATH"))
    exit("No direct script access allowed");

class Cases_back_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }


    public function count_new_cases_reports() {
        $this->db->where("care_status", 0);
        return $this->db->count_all_results("cases_reports");
    }

}
```

it echoes 1 nicely but when calling method in the model i get undefined property error

help please!

Comment: Could you trace where do you call the `$cases_back` property?

Comment: Sorry it is $cases not $cases_back .. i updated the image .. i called it in method count_new_cases_reports()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using HMVC you should extends your controller from `MX_Controller`. Also your controller name should Camel case (assuming you are using version 3+)

Try this

```
//File name should be Back.php
class Back extends MX_Controller {
...
```

and

```
class Admin_cases extends MX_Controller {
....
```

Comment: But i have to extend from Back in Admin_cases .. Back is the parent class which all admin classes should extend from it

Comment: ok then try parent class `Back` as I suggested above and then `Admin_cases` class extend from it(not tested)

Comment: Thanks man :) it worked now when i extended mx in back class .. but i want to know what is the difference between mx_controller and ci_controller

Comment: @eng.ahmed mx controller enable all HMVC functionality where CI controller is base for core codeigniter